# Should SVG favicons be square?

Tags: html, svg, favicon

I know that historically `.ico` and `.png` favicons have always had to be square (have equal width and height – e.g. 16x16, 32x32, 64x64), and even if your actual favicon picture didn't have equal width and height, you still had to put it inside a square template, so to speak, or else browsers would distort the image; like so:

[image]

[image]

However, when it comes to SVG favicons, this doesn't seem to be case. Even if the `viewBox` of your `<svg>` element has different width and height, browsers keep the aspect ratio intact when showing the favicon, unlike what they do to raster favicons:

[image]

So, it sure seems like the old "square rule" for favicons doesn't actually apply to the SVG ones, but I've seen a number of articles casually stating that even SVG favicons should be a square:

> Be sure that the SVG image is **square**. [Here](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/how-to-favicon-in-2021-six-files-that-fit-most-needs#:%7E:text=Prepare%20the%20SVG-,Be%20sure%20that%20the%20SVG%20image%20is%20square.,-Open%20the%20source)

> Actually, if the logo of the company already exists as a **square** SVG image, you can use it as is. [Here](https://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/the-united-svg-favicon-myth/#:%7E:text=them%20or%20more.-,Actually%2C%20if%20the%20logo%20of%20the%20company%20already%20exists%20as%20a%20square%20SVG%20image%2C%20you%20can%20use%20it%20as%20is.,-Look%20Ma%2C%20no)

*(emphasis mine)*

Which is confusing to me. I'm curious whether or not this is true, do SVG favicons actually need to have a square `viewBox`? Or are these little hints in these articles just misguided and mistaken? Is there any evidence suggesting that even SVG favicons must be square?

Comment: SVG favicons dont need to be square, unlike raster favicons. Any aspect ratio that works best for your design can be used. I guess some legacy browsers wont display them correctly or people are just carrying over raster favicon practices to SVGs

Comment: SVG favicons don't even need to keep their aspect ratio. They can be written not to do that.